# I can call a no longer existing JS function but I can't call new JS functions from my view

Tags: javascript, netbeans, jsf-2

I have a problem regarding to a JavaScript function.

I used to have a JS function located in a .js file which is also located in my project's NetBeans directory. I used to invoke that function from a view but later on I decided to change that function and add some new features to that function and call that new function from my view but it worked as in its past version and later on I changed that function's name which officialy means a function with the previous name was totally destroyed and this time I invoke my JS function from its new name and nothing worked. The funny thing is that, I again called that function with its previous name (again, it doesn't exists actually), it works as its past version although I have totally changed that function's name and officially a function with that name no longer exists in my file. What do you fellows think I should do?

Yours ideas and helps are greatly appreciated...

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache?

Comment: Try `alert(typeof yourFunc != 'undefined');`

Comment: As Oded pointed correctly, it sounds like cache issue. Try your demo in incognito or private browsing or clearing all your cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time when you change static/cacheable resources like JavaScripts and CSS files, you'd need to do a hard refresh in your browser. That is, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> after opening the page. It will force the webbrowser to ignore the caching rules on the resources associated with the page and make it to request the resources fresh from the server.